# PyMongo: Access fields returned from document within array resulting from find() query

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I am executing a query like this on a MongoDB collection:

```
 cursor = collection.find({"activityArray":{"$elemMatch":{"sport":0}}},{"activityArray.sport" : 1, "activityArray\|here is result object
.id":1, "endo" : 1})                                                                                                 |20166249
    for result_object in cursor[0:1]:                                                                                |here is result object
        print "here is result object"                                                                                |20166249                                                            |here is result object
        print result_object["endo"]                                                                                  |20166249
#        print result_object["activityArray.sport"]   
#        print result_object["activityArray"]["sport"]   
#        print result_object["sport"]
```

Each of the commented out lines gives me a key error. How can I access those fields returned from a document within an array within a document resulting from a PyMongo query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `activityArray` is an array, you need to have another loop on that list as follows:

```
cursor = collection.find({"activityArray": {"$elemMatch": {"sport":0 }}},{"activityArray.sport" : 1, "activityArray.id":1, "endo" : 1}) 

for result_object in cursor[0:1]:
    print result_object["endo"])
    for activity in result_object["activityArray"]:
        print activity["sport"]
```

Comment: Thanks. I had figured this out in parallel, but what I still don't understand is that I thought $elemMatch returns only the first array element matched? Apparently it actually returns the whole array so long as one element matches?

Comment: @sunny There are two different types of **`$elemMatch`** operators: 1) for [**querying**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch) and the other for [**projection**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch). In your case you used the former instead of the latter.